# Swift3 Version of performSelector and cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to invoke a method using some delay ( 0.2 ms ) in swift 3.0 , What i want is to invoke the method with delay for the first time, and when the same method is invoked again it should cancel the previous invocation if already invoked within those 0.2 seconds. I could see objective c had performSelector and cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget but i am not able to find any examples of same for Swift 3.0 , Can any one please help.

Comment: Look at Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). It provides all you need.

Comment: Or use a Timer and always invalidate the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class has to be subclass of `NSObject` to get these methods.

```
    class MyClass: NSObject {

    func performAction(afterDelay delay: TimeInterval)  {
        perform(#selector(MyClass.action), with: self, afterDelay: delay)
    }

    func action(sender: Any?)  {
        print("action called")
    }

    func cancel() {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.action), object: self)
    }
 }
```

However, if you just need to perform some action fter some delay, you can check GCD methods.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { 
            //you action
        }
```

Comment: do you have a working example of perform and cancelPreviousPerformRequests in swift 3 ?

Comment: I have already added example. Which part of it is not clear to you?

Comment: @Max great. 